# Python: generate python code from tree

Tags: python, tree, code-formatting, lark-parser

I've build syntax tree using lark

```
Tree(if, [Tree(condition, [Token(VARIABLE, 'x'), Token(ACTION_OPERATOR, '>'), Token(SIGNED_NUMBER, '18')]), Tree(result, [Tree(if, [Tree(condition, [Token(VARIABLE, 'y'), Token(ACTION_OPERATOR, '>'), Token(SIGNED_NUMBER, '500000')]), Tree(result, [Token(STRING, 'switch_credit_type')]), Tree(condition, [Token(VARIABLE, 'y'), Token(ACTION_OPERATOR, '<'), Token(SIGNED_NUMBER, '50000')]), Tree(result, [Tree(if, [Tree(condition, [Token(VARIABLE, 'z'), Token(ACTION_OPERATOR, '>'), Token(SIGNED_NUMBER, '2')]), Tree(result, [Token(STRING, 'success')]), Tree(condition, [Token(VARIABLE, 'z'), Token(ACTION_OPERATOR, '<'), Token(SIGNED_NUMBER, '1')]), Tree(result, [Tree(if, [Tree(condition, [Token(VARIABLE, 'a'), Token(ACTION_OPERATOR, '>'), Token(VARIABLE, 'y')]), Tree(result, [Token(STRING, 'refused')]), Tree(else, [Token(STRING, 'get_more_info')])])]), Tree(else, [Token(STRING, 'get_more_info')])])]), Tree(else, [Token(STRING, 'fail')])])])])
```

I need to generate python code from it (condition)
But I have problem with indents and try to build code generator automatically

```
code = []
add_indent = ''

def py_cond_gen(t, level=0):
    global code, add_indent
    if t.data == 'if':
        code.append('if')
        for i, child in enumerate(t.children):
            if child.data == 'condition':
                if code[-1] != 'if':
                    code.append('elif')
                condition_expr = ' '.join([str(children) for children in child.children]) + ':\n\t' + add_indent
                code.append(condition_expr)
            if child.data == 'result':
                if type(child.children[0]).__name__ == 'Tree' and child.children[0].data == 'if':
                    add_indent = '\t' * (level+1)
                    py_cond_gen(child.children[0], level=level+1)
                    add_indent = add_indent[:level-2]
                else:
                    code.append("print('%s')" % child.children[0] + '\n' + add_indent[:level-2])
            if child.data == 'else':
                code.append('else:\n\t' + add_indent[:level-2])
                code.append("print('%s')" % child.children[0] + '\n' + add_indent[:level-2])
```

But there is extra indentation and I have no idea no how can I fix that.
But I get

```
if x > 10:
    if y > 500000:
        print('switch_credit_type')
    elif y < 50000:
        if z > 2:
            print('success')
        elif z < 1:
            if a > y:
                print('refused')
            else:
                print('get_more_info')
        else:
            print('get_more_info')
    else:
        print('fail')
```

instead

```
if x > 10:
    if y > 500000:
        print('switch_credit_type')
    elif y < 50000:
        if z > 2:
            print('success')
        elif z < 1:
            if a > y:
                print('refused')
            else:
                print('get_more_info')
    else:
        print('get_more_info')
else:
    print('fail')
```

Comment: Your `elif` blocks are correctly indented, only your `else` blocks are wrong.

Comment: So perhaps you should not be using `add_indent[:level-2]` but use `add_indent`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters everywhere?

Comment: Hrm, no, actually, the error is in the `elif` handling it appears, because your inner-most `if ... else` has the right indentation. Why are you adding indentation *after* your lines, out of interest?

Comment: @MartijnPieters because with `\n` I transfer to a new string. So I need to add indents and I do it with `\t`

Comment: @MartijnPieters is any way to fix that? I've broken my head

Comment: No, you need to add indents to the **current** line, never the next.

Comment: @PetrPetrov If you post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can run I could try to help you out